# Getting "passwords do not match" on my app everytime; Problem with the code maybe validation or api request

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, flutter-layout

I have tried making an authentication screen for my app I am unable to signup as it's showing the password does not match as I have set up a text form validation.
The data is not also showing up in the firebase authentication so I think there could be a problem with the API request. I have not put.json after the URI.parse for auth as i saw somewhere we don't(tried after putting it but it did not work).

Authentication screen:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../Providers/auth.dart';

enum AuthMode { Signup, Login }

class AuthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/auth';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // final transformConfig = Matrix4.rotationZ(-8 * pi / 180);
    // transformConfig.translate(-10.0);
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(215, 117, 255, 1).withOpacity(0.5),
                  Color.fromRGBO(255, 188, 117, 1).withOpacity(0.9),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                stops: [0, 1],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: deviceSize.height,
              width: deviceSize.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 94.0),
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          -8 * pi / 180) //allows to rotate the container
                        ..translate(
                            -10.0), //adds offset to matrix; ..  operater changes the product from inside
                      // ..translate(-10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                            offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'MyShop',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors
                              .black, //Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.title.color,
                          fontSize: 50,
                          fontFamily: 'Anton',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: deviceSize.width > 600 ? 2 : 1,
                    child: AuthCard(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthCard({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthCardState createState() => _AuthCardState();
}

class _AuthCardState extends State<AuthCard> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  AuthMode _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
  Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
  };
  var _isLoading = false;
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _submit() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      // Invalid!
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
      // Log user in
    } else {
      // Sign user up
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signup(
          //as signup returns future we have to aysnc it, we do await to show loading spinner
          _authData['email'].toString(),
          _authData['password']
              .toString()); //authdata is the value we are saviing this as
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _switchAuthMode() {
    if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.Signup;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 8.0,
      child: Container(
        height: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 320 : 260,
        constraints:
            BoxConstraints(minHeight: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 320 : 260),
        width: deviceSize.width * 0.75,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                      return 'Invalid email!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['email'] = value.toString();
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  obscureText:
                      true, //which makes sure that the inpur isnt shown to the user
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                      return 'Password is too short!';
                    }
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['password'] = value.toString();
                  },
                ),
                if (_authMode == AuthMode.Signup)
                  TextFormField(
                    enabled: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup
                        ? (value) {
                            if (value != _passwordController.text) {
                              return 'Passwords do not match!';
                            }
                          }
                        : null,
                  ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                if (_isLoading)
                  CircularProgressIndicator()
                else
                  RaisedButton(
                    child:
                        Text(_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP'),
                    onPressed: _submit,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button!.color,
                  ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                      '${_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'SIGNUP' : 'LOGIN'} INSTEAD'),
                  onPressed: _switchAuthMode,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4),
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Auth.dart:

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  
  late String _token; 
  late DateTime _expiryDate;
  late String _userId;

  Future<void> signup(String username, String password) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[Auth Key]');
    final response = await http.post(url,
        body: jsonEncode({
          'username': username,
          'password': password,
          'returnSecureToken':
              true 
        }));
    print(json.decode(response.body));
  }
}
```

Also, getting no error message or any messages in debug console. Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need have separate `TextEditingController` for each of your `TextFormField` widgets, if you'd like to read the values with `controller.value`.

You also have to assign the appropriate controller to each `TextFormField` like this:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _controllerForThisField,
  ...
),
```

Also, do not forget to properly dispose all controllers when the widget is disposed, call `controller.dispose()` for example in an overridden `dispose()` method.